# Does the Internet Protocol do Routing?

Tags: networking, routes, ip

Many sources in the web have different opinion on this. It is obvious that the Internet Protocol speicfied in RFC 791 is responsible for addressing host interfaces, encapsulating data into datagrams (including fragmentation and reassembly). But what is about routing? Is this the function of IP or is this realized by the protocols RIP, OSPF nad BGP?

Answer (score 0):

The word "routing" has two closely related meanings:

1) As RFC 791 section 1.4 says "The selection of a path for transmission is called routing." When a layer 3 packet (IP datagram) arrives on an incoming interface, the router does a longest-prefix-match lookup in the routing table to decide on which outgoing interface and next-hop the packet should be forwarded.

2) The act of filling the routing tables, by running some routing protocol such as RIP, OSPF, or BGP is also called "routing".

The former is often done in hardware, and the latter is done in software.

When the difference matters, the former is often called forwarding (hence "FIB" for Forwarding Information Base) and the latter is called routing (hence "RIB" for Routing Information Base).